# Stop fitting with AdaBoost, decrease learning rate and then keep refitting

Tags: python, scikit-learn, adaboost

I am currently using an AdaBoost Classifier.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html

I would like to run it with 400 estimators and default learning rate (1.0). Then once the zero_one_loss starts to plauteau, I would like to decrease the learning rate and keep fitting.

My current code works as follows:

```
dt_stump = sktree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=maxDepth, min_samples_leaf=1)
ada = skensemble.AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=dt_stump, learning_rate=learning_rate1, n_estimators=nEstimators1, algorithm=algo)
ada.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

I would like to do something like:

```
ada.learning_rate = learning_rate2
ada.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

But I am not entirely sure if that is the correct way. Or if I should also change the number of estimators. Or if it's correct to just run ada.fit(X_train, Y_train) again.

Is there any sample script or example it's possible to take a look at?

Many thanks!

Comment: Is your requirement to use AdaBoostClassifier only and anneal the learning rate when it plateaus? Or would you be open to another classifier?

Comment: The first option would be preferable (AdaBoostClassifier only).